# Cancel/Pause/Stop any Interstitial Ads

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android App which displays Interstitial Ads using Googles admob network. The good thing about admob is, its activity independent. I can load the ad in my MainActivity and whenever admob is ready with the ad, it will display it, even when I am not in MainActivity anymore. I already use the `isLoaded()` method to show the ad, and thats 90% of the time already working as desired.

But the other 10% it is not. There are certain activities which should remain adfree because the ad will decrease the quality of the game. If a phone is slow or the connection is slow and it takes a while to load an ad, the ad might pop up in the wrong activity.

Is there something I could call, which would close loaded ads and stops loading ads which are not displayed yet? This would take effect only on two activities whilst the others will remain as they are.

so in my main activity I call:

```
Ads.loadAdMobInterstitial(MainActivity.this);
```

and this is my class which handles Ads:

```
public class Ads {

    public static InterstitialAd loadAdMobInterstitial(final Context context) {

            int admobUnitId = string.admob_ad_unit_id; 

            final InterstitialAd iAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
            iAd.setAdUnitId(context.getString(admobUnitId));

            iAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                        iAd.show();
                }

            });     

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

            iAd.loadAd(adRequest);

            return iAd;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, first of all, you should **NEVER**  call `interstitialAd.show()` from `onAdLoaded()`. As you have pointed out it will cause a poor user experience. It is also likely to get your Admob account banned.

I suspect that what you really want to do is to refactor your existing Activities into Fragments and host them all within your MainActivity. That way you will have the control you need to switch the interstitial on/off.

And make sure that you are showing your interstitial from a natural break point in your app rather than from `onAdLoaded()`.

Comment: well right now refactoring activities into fragments is not an option, it would be too time consuming. anyway, showing the ad anywhere in the app is fine except the two activities, so there is no way to do it?

Comment: Not the way you are trying to do it no.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean flag in your `onPause`/`onResume` methods in the activity or fragment. Then check on adLoaded event like this:

```
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
             public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if(!paused) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your interstitial ad in background, but don't use onAdLoaded() method.

When you are at the point in the app, where you want to show your interstitial, use this:

```
if (admobInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
    admobInterstitial.show();
}
```

This will show interstitial ad only in case it is loaded. Otherwise nothing will happen.